# How many roots does this polynomial have in $\mathbb{Z}/91\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: number-theory

$f(x)=x^8-1$

I know how I would do this problem if the mod wasn't so high. Not sure how to approach this question.

Comment: Remember: 91 is the worlds most mysterious prime, aka 7*13

Comment: In addition to deinst's comment also avail services of Fermat's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, $ \mathbb{Z}/91\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{F}_7 \times \mathbb{F}_{13} $ so it suffices to solve $ X^8 - 1 = 0 $ simultaneously in $ \mathbb{F}_7 $ and $ \mathbb{F}_{13} $. Now, the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, therefore for any $ d | p-1 $ there are precisely $ \phi(d) $ elements of order $ d $.

$X^8 - 1 = 0$ implies that $ X $ has order 1, 2, 4 or 8. It cannot have order 8 as $ 8 $ does not divide $ 13 - 1 = 12 $, and the equation then has $ \phi(1) + \phi(2) + \phi(4) = 4 $ solutions in $ \mathbb{F}_{13} $. In $ \mathbb{F}_7 $ the equation reduces to $ X^2 - 1 $ by Fermat's little theorem, which has two roots $1$ and $ 6 $. We conclude that there are a total number of $ 2 \cdot 4 = 8 $ solutions in $ \mathbb{Z}/91\mathbb{Z} $.

Answer (score 2):

We want to solve the question without Chinese theorem. One has 
$$x^8-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$$  Note that $a^8=(-a)^8$ so each solution $a$ gives another solution $-a$. Besides $x^8=(x^2)^4=(x^4)^2$ hence if $a$ is solution of $x^8\equiv 1\pmod{91}$  then $a^2$ is solution  of $x^4\equiv 1\pmod{91}$ and $a^4$ is solution of $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{91}$.

► Neither $x^2+1\equiv 0\pmod {91}$ nor $x^4+1\equiv 0\pmod {91}$  has  solution

because $(\mathbb F_7)^2=\{1,4,9,0\}$  and $(\mathbb F_7)^4=\{1,2,4,0\}$ so

$a^2+1\in\{2,5,10,1\}$ and $a^4+1\in\{2,3,5,1\}$ and any element is such that $a^2+1=0$ or

$a^4+1=0$  in $\mathbb F_7$.

►►Because of $(x^4-1)=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)$, it follows the equations to solve are $$\begin {cases}x^4-1\equiv 0\pmod {91}\\ x^2-1\equiv 0\pmod {91}\end{cases}$$ 
Calculation gives $8^4=45\cdot 91+1$ which implies the solutions $\pm 8$ and $\pm 8^2$.

**Besides  $34^4\equiv =8\cdot 91+1$ so $\pm27$ are solutions**. We have finally, with the

obvious solutions $\pm1$ the solutions
             $$\color{red}{\{\pm1,\pm8,\pm64,\pm27\}}$$

**EDITION**.-I leave "**Besides $34^4\equiv =8\cdot 91+1$ so $\pm27$ are solutions**" in order the reader can see the obvious lapse I made. It is clear I wanted to write  "Besides $34^4 =8\cdot 91+1$ so $\pm34$ are solutions". Thus the solutions are $$\color{blue}{\{\pm1,\pm8,\pm64,\pm34\}}$$

**My purpose was mainly to give a solution without Chinese remainder theorem that I found interesting**. I hope @Daniel Robert-Nicoud delete his downvote now.

Comment: Remark: $64 = -27$ in the ring we're working on. Also, looking at the other answers it appears that you're missing some solutions.

Comment: It was an obvious lapse because I have written $34^4=8\cdot 91+1$ so $\pm 27$ are solutions instead of $\pm 34$ are solutions. (actually I have written $34^4\equiv=8\cdot+1$. (The solutions you say I missed are in the negative ones I put).

Comment: Downvote removed :)

Comment: Thank you. Une salutation à Joseph Oesterlé (sa conjecture abc est diaboliquement vrai!)

Answer (score 0):

The following criterion is often used (see for example the book of Ireland and Rosen "A classical introduction to modern number theory").
If $x^n\equiv a \bmod m$ is solvable , then there are exactly $(n,\phi(m))$ solutions. For $n=8$ and $m=91$ we have $(n,\phi(m))=(8,72)=8$ solutions, and it is not difficult to find these solutions, using Fermat's little theorem, or elementary computations modulo $7$ and $13$, namely
$n=1,8,27,34,57,64,83,90$.